# O meu calendário só exibe o primeiro compromisso agendado de cada dia

Tags: php, mysql

Montei um calendário com agenda em PHP + MySQL , o mesmo já esta em 80% do desenvolvimento.

Mas, estou com um problema, tipo se eu cadastro em evento para o dia 20/07, esse compromisso é exibido normalmente no calendário. Se eu marco outro compromisso para o mesmo dia, o calendário só exibe o primeiro compromisso agendado. Mas eu queria que fosse exibido todos os compromissos do dia.

Segue o código completo do mesmo.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<?php

 $idUsuario = ($_SESSION['UsuarioID']);

 $mes=date('m');
 $ano=date('Y');

 if($mes == 1) 
 {
 $qtdDiasMes=31;
 $nomeMesMes="Janeiro";
 }
 if($mes == 2) 
 {
 $qtdDiasMes=28;
 $nomeMes="Fevereiro";
 }
 if($mes == 3) 
 {
 $qtdDiasMes=31;
 $nomeMes="Março";
 }
 if($mes == 4) 
 {
 $qtdDiasMes=30;
 $nomeMes="Abril";
 }
 if($mes == 5)
 {
 $qtdDiasMes=31;
 $nomeMes="Maio";
 }
 if($mes == 6) 
 {
 $qtdDiasMes=30;
 $nomeMes="Junho";
 }
 if($mes == 7) 
 {
 $qtdDiasMes=31;
 $nomeMes="Julho";
 }
 if($mes == 8) 
 {
 $qtdDiasMes=31;
 $nomeMes="Agosto";
 }
 if($mes == 9) 
 {
 $qtdDiasMes=30;
 $nomeMes="Setembro";
 }
 if($mes == 10)
 {
 $qtdDiasMes=31;
 $nomeMes="Outubro";
 }
 if($mes == 11)
 {
 $qtdDiasMes=30;
 $nomeMes="Novembro";
 }
 if($mes == 12)
 {
 $qtdDiasMes=31;
 $nomeMes="Dezembro";
 }
?>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <a data-toggle="modal" href='#formAddEvent'>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-default">Novo Compromisso</button>
            </a>
         </div>
    </div>

    <div class="modal fade" id="formAddEvent" tabindex="-1" role="basic" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">

                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button>
                                    <h4 class="modal-title">
                                        <strong>Cadastro de novo compromisso </strong>
                                    </h4>
                            </div>

                            <div class="modal-body">

                                    <div class="portlet-body form">

                                        <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="addEvent" autocomplete="off">

                                            <div class="form-body">

                                                <div class="row">
                                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                            <label class="control-label col-md-4"><font color="red">Data do evento</font></label>
                                                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                                                    <input type="date" class="form-control" id="txtData"  name="txtData">
                                                                    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="txtIdUsuario"  name="txtIdUsuario" value="<?=$idUsuario;?>">
                                                                </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>

                                                <div class="row">
                                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                            <label class="control-label col-md-4">Assunto</label>
                                                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtAssunto"  name="txtAssunto">
                                                                </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>

                                                <div class="row">
                                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                            <label class="control-label col-md-4">Lembrete</label>
                                                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                                                    <textarea id="txtMensagem" name="txtMensagem"> </textarea>
                                                                </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div><!--::: ROW :: -->

                                            </div><!-- Form Body -->

                                    </div><!-- portlet form-body -->
                            </div><!-- modal body -->

                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                            <button type="submit" name="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-success btn-default">Salvar</button>
                                            <button type="button" class="btn default" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>

                                            </form>
                                    </div>
                    </div><!-- modal content -->
            </div>
    </div>

        <hr>            

            <div class="row">
                    <div class="portlet box red">
                        <div class="portlet-title">
                            <div class="caption">
                                <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>Minha Agenda
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="portlet-body">

                            <div class="row">
                               <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <p align="center"><font size="6">
                                            <b><?php echo $nomeMes . " de " . $ano;  ?></b>
                                    </font></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">


                                    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" width="350" height="450" align="center">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td width=30><center>Dom</center></td>
                                            <td width=30><center>Seg</center></td>
                                            <td width=30><center>Ter</center></td>
                                            <td width=30><center>Qua</center></td>
                                            <td width=30><center>Qui</center></td>
                                            <td width=30><center>Sex</center></td>
                                            <td width=30><center>Sab</center></td>
                                        </tr>

        <?php

                echo "<tr align='center'>";

                        for($i=1; $i<=$qtdDiasMes;$i++)
                            {
                                $diadasemana = date("w",mktime(0,0,0,$mes,$i,$ano));
                                    $cont = 0;
                                    if($i == 1)
                                        {
                                            while($cont < $diadasemana)
                                                {
                                                    echo "<td width='194' height='107' style='size:12px;'>   </td>";
                                                    $cont++;
                                                }
                                        }

                                        if($i >=1 and $i <= 9){
                                            $dataCalendar = $ano.'-'.$mes.'-'.'0'.$i;  //pega o Ano  , o mes  , e o dia que recebe o valor de $i 
                                        } else{
                                            $dataCalendar = $ano.'-'.$mes.'-'.$i;  //pega o Ano  , o mes  , e o dia que recebe o valor de $i
                                        }


                                            $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblAgenda where data = '$dataCalendar' and idUsuario = $idUsuario");
                                            $row = mysql_fetch_array ($sql);

                                                $assunto = $row['assunto'];
                                                $idModal = $row['id'];


                            echo " <td width='194' height='107' style='size:12px;' >"
                                    .$i;
                                    // dia da semana

                            echo"  <center>
                                        <a data-toggle='modal' href='#".$idModal."'>
                                            ".$assunto."
                                        </a>
                                    </center>";


                                echo    "</td>";



                                if($diadasemana == 6)
                                    {
                                        echo "</tr>";

                                        echo "<tr align='center'>";
                                    }
                            }

                echo "</tr>";
?>

                        </table>

                                </div>

                            </div><!-- ::: ROW ::: -->
                        </div><!-- PORTLED BODY -->
                    </div><!-- PORTLED BOX -->
            </div><!-- ROW -->






<?php

    // parte que faz os Modals aparecerem.

    $sql2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblAgenda where idUsuario = $idUsuario");
    while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array ($sql2))
    {
        $assuntoModal = $row2['assunto'];
        $mensagem = $row2['mensagem'];
        $idEvent = $row2['id'];
        echo '

    <div class="modal fade" id="'.$idEvent.'" tabindex="-1" role="basic" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button>
                                <h4 class="modal-title">'.$assuntoModal.'</h4>
                    </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                '.$mensagem.'
                            </div>
                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                            <button type="button" class="btn default" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
                                    </div>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>';
    }


if(isset($_POST['btnSubmit'])){

$idUsuario = $_POST['txtIdUsuario'];
$data = $_POST['txtData'];
$assunto = $_POST['txtAssunto'];
$mensagem = $_POST['txtMensagem'];


            $sqlCadastro = "INSERT INTO tblAgenda
            (idUsuario,assunto,mensagem,data) VALUES ($idUsuario,'$assunto','$mensagem','$data')";

            mysql_query($sqlCadastro) or die (mysql_error() . 'Por favor , verifique se todos os dados estão preenchidos corretamente'); 

            if(mysql_affected_rows() == 1) //verifica se foi afetada alguma linha, nesse caso inserida alguma linha
                    {
                        echo"   <script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
                                    alert('Compromisso agendado com sucesso');window.location.href='/admin2/perfil/agenda'
                                </script>";
                    }

                else
                {
                    echo"<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
                    alert('Não foi possível enviar esse formulario');window.location.href='/admin2/contatos/lista-de-contatos'
                    </script>";
                }
}
```

A minha tabela `tblAgenda`:

```
id  int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT  Primária 
idUsuario   int(11) 
assunto varchar(200)    latin1_swedish_ci       
mensagem    varchar(999)    latin1_swedish_ci
data    date
```

O código esta bem bacana e da para alguém usar se quiser, pois está de fácil entendimento. Sempre procurei na internet mas nunca tinha achado algo do tipo.

Se alguém me puder ajudar a melhorar o código vai me ajudar e ajudar muitos outros.

Comment: Gosto de usar esse cara aqui quando trabalho com calendários: http://fullcalendar.io/. Ele integra bem com o backend utilizando Ajax.

Comment: Na edição do AP: "Mostrei a um amigo , e foi só adcionar um while entre os <td> </td> que exibe o assunto . Fica aqui o código para quem quiser um calendário com agenda em php + mysql . Que puder ajudar a melhorar o código ,via ajudar \o/ "

Comment: Henrique eu vou reverter a sua pergunta. Coloque o código com as alterações como resposta. Aqui fazemos perguntas e respostas. E depois marcamos a resposta certa.

Answer (score 1):

@Jorge B.

Desculpe, nao sabia .

Segue o código com o problema resolvido.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<?php

 $idUsuario = ($_SESSION['UsuarioID']);

 $mes=date('m');
 $ano=date('Y');

 if($mes == 1) 
 {
 $qtdDiasMes=31;
 $nomeMesMes="Janeiro";
 }
 if($mes == 2) 
 {
 $qtdDiasMes=28;
 $nomeMes="Fevereiro";
 }
 if($mes == 3) 
 {
 $qtdDiasMes=31;
 $nomeMes="Março";
 }
 if($mes == 4) 
 {
 $qtdDiasMes=30;
 $nomeMes="Abril";
 }
 if($mes == 5)
 {
 $qtdDiasMes=31;
 $nomeMes="Maio";
 }
 if($mes == 6) 
 {
 $qtdDiasMes=30;
 $nomeMes="Junho";
 }
 if($mes == 7) 
 {
 $qtdDiasMes=31;
 $nomeMes="Julho";
 }
 if($mes == 8) 
 {
 $qtdDiasMes=31;
 $nomeMes="Agosto";
 }
 if($mes == 9) 
 {
 $qtdDiasMes=30;
 $nomeMes="Setembro";
 }
 if($mes == 10)
 {
 $qtdDiasMes=31;
 $nomeMes="Outubro";
 }
 if($mes == 11)
 {
 $qtdDiasMes=30;
 $nomeMes="Novembro";
 }
 if($mes == 12)
 {
 $qtdDiasMes=31;
 $nomeMes="Dezembro";
 }
?>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <a data-toggle="modal" href='#formAddEvent'>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-default">Novo Compromisso</button>
            </a>
         </div>
    </div>

    <div class="modal fade" id="formAddEvent" tabindex="-1" role="basic" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">

                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button>
                                    <h4 class="modal-title">
                                        <strong>Cadastro de novo compromisso </strong>
                                    </h4>
                            </div>

                            <div class="modal-body">

                                    <div class="portlet-body form">

                                        <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="addEvent" autocomplete="off">

                                            <div class="form-body">

                                                <div class="row">
                                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                            <label class="control-label col-md-4"><font color="red">Data do evento</font></label>
                                                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                                                    <input type="date" class="form-control" id="txtData"  name="txtData" required />
                                                                    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="txtIdUsuario"  name="txtIdUsuario" value="<?=$idUsuario;?>">
                                                                </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>

                                                <div class="row">
                                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                            <label class="control-label col-md-4">Assunto</label>
                                                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                                                    <select class="form-control" id="txtAssunto"  name="txtAssunto" required>
                                                                        <option value="Retorno">Retorno</option>
                                                                        <option value="atualizar dados">Atualizar dados de venda</option>
                                                                    </select>
                                                                </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>

                                                <div class="row">
                                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                            <label class="control-label col-md-4">Lembrete</label>
                                                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                                                    <textarea id="txtMensagem" name="txtMensagem" required> </textarea>
                                                                </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div><!--::: ROW :: -->

                                            </div><!-- Form Body -->

                                    </div><!-- portlet form-body -->
                            </div><!-- modal body -->

                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                            <button type="submit" name="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-success btn-default">Salvar</button>
                                            <button type="button" class="btn default" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>

                                            </form>
                                    </div>
                    </div><!-- modal content -->
            </div>
    </div>

        <hr>            

            <div class="row">
                    <div class="portlet box red">
                        <div class="portlet-title">
                            <div class="caption">
                                <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>Minha Agenda
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="portlet-body">

                            <div class="row">
                               <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <p align="center"><font size="6">
                                            <b><?php echo $nomeMes . " de " . $ano;  ?></b>
                                    </font></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">


                                    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" width="350" height="450" align="center">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td width=30><center>Dom</center></td>
                                            <td width=30><center>Seg</center></td>
                                            <td width=30><center>Ter</center></td>
                                            <td width=30><center>Qua</center></td>
                                            <td width=30><center>Qui</center></td>
                                            <td width=30><center>Sex</center></td>
                                            <td width=30><center>Sab</center></td>
                                        </tr>

        <?php

                echo "<tr align='center'>";

                        for($i=1; $i<=$qtdDiasMes;$i++)
                            {
                                $diadasemana = date("w",mktime(0,0,0,$mes,$i,$ano));
                                    $cont = 0;
                                    if($i == 1)
                                        {
                                            while($cont < $diadasemana)
                                                {
                                                    echo "<td width='194' height='107' style='size:12px;'>   </td>";
                                                    $cont++;
                                                }
                                        }

                                        if($i >=1 and $i <= 9){
                                            $dataCalendar = $ano.'-'.$mes.'-'.'0'.$i;  //pega o Ano  , o mes  , e o dia que recebe o valor de $i 
                                        } else{
                                            $dataCalendar = $ano.'-'.$mes.'-'.$i;  //pega o Ano  , o mes  , e o dia que recebe o valor de $i
                                        }


                                        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblAgenda where data = '$dataCalendar' and idUsuario = $idUsuario");  


                            echo " <td width='194' height='107' style='size:12px;' >";

                                    echo $i;    // dia da semana

                                    while($row = mysql_fetch_array ($sql)){

                                        $assunto = $row['assunto'];
                                        $idModal = $row['id'];



                            echo" 
                                        <a data-toggle='modal' href='#".$idModal."'>
                                            <ul style='list-style-type: none;'>
                                                <li style='align:left !important;'>";

                                                    if($assunto != null){
                                                     echo "<button class='btn btn-success'>".$assunto."</button>";
                                                    } else{
                                                        echo $assunto;
                                                    }

                                        echo  "</li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </a>";
                                    }

                                echo    "</td>";



                                if($diadasemana == 6)
                                    {
                                        echo "</tr>";

                                        echo "<tr align='center'>";
                                    }
                            }

                echo "</tr>";
?>

                        </table>

                                </div>

                            </div><!-- ::: ROW ::: -->
                        </div><!-- PORTLED BODY -->
                    </div><!-- PORTLED BOX -->
            </div><!-- ROW -->






<?php

    // parte que faz os Modals aparecerem.

    $sql2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblAgenda where idUsuario = $idUsuario");
    while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array ($sql2))
    {
        $assuntoModal = $row2['assunto'];
        $mensagem = $row2['mensagem'];
        $idEvent = $row2['id'];
        echo '

    <div class="modal fade" id="'.$idEvent.'" tabindex="-1" role="basic" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button>
                                <h4 class="modal-title">'.$assuntoModal.'</h4>
                    </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                '.$mensagem.'
                            </div>
                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                            <button type="button" class="btn default" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
                                    </div>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>';
    }


if(isset($_POST['btnSubmit'])){

$idUsuario = $_POST['txtIdUsuario'];
$data = $_POST['txtData'];
$assunto = $_POST['txtAssunto'];
$mensagem = $_POST['txtMensagem'];


            $sqlCadastro = "INSERT INTO tblAgenda
            (idUsuario,assunto,mensagem,data) VALUES ($idUsuario,'$assunto','$mensagem','$data')";

            mysql_query($sqlCadastro) or die (mysql_error() . 'Por favor , verifique se todos os dados estão preenchidos corretamente'); 

            if(mysql_affected_rows() == 1) //verifica se foi afetada alguma linha, nesse caso inserida alguma linha
                    {
                        echo"   <script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
                                    alert('Compromisso agendado com sucesso');window.location.href='/admin2/perfil/agenda'
                                </script>";
                    }

                else
                {
                    echo"<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
                    alert('Não foi possível enviar esse formulario');window.location.href='/admin2/contatos/lista-de-contatos'
                    </script>";
                }
}
```